# How to getElementsByClassName by using python xml.dom.minidom?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, minidom

I want to obtain the body of all elements that do have a specific class.

Python xml.dom.minidom has a method for getting an element  by id, `getElementById()` but I need to get all elements that do have a specific class.

How do I obtain this?

Note, if this is not possible using minidom, please provide a simple alternative that would allow me to get the full content of the elements of this class. By full content I mean also all the subnodes and text below them, as a simple string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommended you to use [lxml](http://lxml.de) instead of xml.dom.minidom.

Using lxml.html / cssselect:

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring(document_string)
for elem in root.cssselect('elem.class'):
    print(elem.tag)
    print(elem.get('src'))
```

---

Using lxml.etree / xpath:

```
import lxml.etree

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(document_string)
for elem in root.xpath('.//elem[contains(@class, "class")]'):
    print(elem.tag)
    print(elem.get('src'))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: how would you do it in minidom?